# Mongo client blocking event loop in vertx

Tags: mongodb, client, vert.x, event-loop

We are using vertx mongo client in our application we are seeing lot of WARNINGS in our log with the following trace.

```
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 12376 ms, time limit is 2000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
        at org.bson.io.OutputBuffer.writeInt32(OutputBuffer.java:64)
        at org.bson.BsonBinaryWriter.backpatchSize(BsonBinaryWriter.java:413)
        at org.bson.BsonBinaryWriter.doWriteEndDocument(BsonBinaryWriter.java:133)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeEndDocument(AbstractBsonWriter.java:305)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeDocument(AbstractJsonCodec.java:265)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeValue(AbstractJsonCodec.java:105)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.lambda$writeArray$2(AbstractJsonCodec.java:298)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec$$Lambda$241/1475070818.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:145)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:23)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeArray(AbstractJsonCodec.java:298)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeValue(AbstractJsonCodec.java:90)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.lambda$writeDocument$1(AbstractJsonCodec.java:261)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec$$Lambda$208/1973630601.accept(Unknown Source)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.lambda$forEach$0(JsonObjectCodec.java:120)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec$$Lambda$209/428413256.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:119)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:23)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeDocument(AbstractJsonCodec.java:258)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeValue(AbstractJsonCodec.java:105)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.lambda$writeArray$2(AbstractJsonCodec.java:298)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec$$Lambda$241/1475070818.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:145)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:23)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeArray(AbstractJsonCodec.java:298)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeValue(AbstractJsonCodec.java:90)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.lambda$writeDocument$1(AbstractJsonCodec.java:261)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec$$Lambda$208/1973630601.accept(Unknown Source)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.lambda$forEach$0(JsonObjectCodec.java:120)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec$$Lambda$209/428413256.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:119)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.JsonObjectCodec.forEach(JsonObjectCodec.java:23)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.writeDocument(AbstractJsonCodec.java:258)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.codec.json.AbstractJsonCodec.encode(AbstractJsonCodec.java:28)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:381)
        at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:371)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writeDocument(BsonWriterHelper.java:74)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayload(BsonWriterHelper.java:58)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BsonWriterHelper.writePayloadArray(BsonWriterHelper.java:50)
        at com.mongodb.connection.SplittablePayloadBsonWriter.writeEndDocument(SplittablePayloadBsonWriter.java:53)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:118)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.addDocumentWithPayload(CommandMessage.java:166)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(CommandMessage.java:148)
        at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encode(RequestMessage.java:145)
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceiveAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:321)
        at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceiveAsync(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:113)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceiveAsync(DefaultConnectionPool.java:452)
        at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.executeAsync(CommandProtocolImpl.java:91)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.executeAsync(DefaultServer.java:200)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocolAsync(DefaultServerConnection.java:279)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.commandAsync(DefaultServerConnection.java:151)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeCommandAsync(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:382)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeBatchesAsync(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:314)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.access$900(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:66)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$2$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:233)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.validateWriteRequests(OperationHelper.java:175)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$2.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:216)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$7.onResult(OperationHelper.java:525)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$7.onResult(OperationHelper.java:522)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:99)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$1.onResult(DefaultServer.java:90)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.openAsync(DefaultConnectionPool.java:189)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.getAsync(DefaultConnectionPool.java:146)
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnectionAsync(DefaultServer.java:90)
        at com.mongodb.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$AsyncClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(AsyncClusterBinding.java:114)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:522)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.access$100(OperationHelper.java:61)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$AsyncCallableWithConnectionAndSourceCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:542)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$AsyncCallableWithConnectionAndSourceCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:530)
        at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
        at com.mongodb.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$1.onResult(AsyncClusterBinding.java:88)
        at com.mongodb.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$1.onResult(AsyncClusterBinding.java:82)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster$ServerSelectionRequest.onResult(BaseCluster.java:421)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.handleServerSelectionRequest(BaseCluster.java:285)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServerAsync(BaseCluster.java:145)
        at com.mongodb.binding.AsyncClusterBinding.getAsyncClusterBindingConnectionSource(AsyncClusterBinding.java:82)
        at com.mongodb.binding.AsyncClusterBinding.getWriteConnectionSource(AsyncClusterBinding.java:77)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:481)
        at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.executeAsync(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:210)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.AsyncOperationExecutorImpl$2.onResult(AsyncOperationExecutorImpl.java:100)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.AsyncOperationExecutorImpl$2.onResult(AsyncOperationExecutorImpl.java:92)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$2.onResult(ClientSessionHelper.java:73)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$2.onResult(ClientSessionHelper.java:67)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster$ServerSelectionRequest.onResult(BaseCluster.java:421)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.handleServerSelectionRequest(BaseCluster.java:285)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServerAsync(BaseCluster.java:145)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper.createClientSession(ClientSessionHelper.java:62)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper.withClientSession(ClientSessionHelper.java:48)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.AsyncOperationExecutorImpl.execute(AsyncOperationExecutorImpl.java:92)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1114)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:522)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:501)
        at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:496)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.saveWithOptions(MongoClientImpl.java:137)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.save(MongoClientImpl.java:124)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:125)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:86)
        at myclass.lambda$getSdkUserAsJson$1(SdkUserDAOImpl.java:51)
        at myclass$$Lambda$219/713859302.handle(Unknown Source)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl.lambda$null$11(MongoClientImpl.java:758)
        at io.vertx.ext.mongo.impl.MongoClientImpl$$Lambda$210/38059280.handle(Unknown Source)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:339)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$28/1005091648.run(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

Is mongo client blocking main event loop, because we have zookeeper configured which expects response from main event loop for every 30 seconds, As event loop blocked zookeeper is removing my application node from the cluster.

Application Flow **-> denotes success handler callback**

> Getcall from Collection A-> Insert record to Collection B -> Insert
>   record to Collectoin C-> end routing context.

```
Note: The writes on the table for mongo client are very high.
```

Comment: The above error keeps on coming in our logs for every two seconds and application is getting out of zookeeper cluster due to the above error.

Comment: How many documents are your trying to insert at once?

Comment: @tsegismont we are uploading only one document at a time.